# Android Programming creating own View

Tags: android

At the moment I'm trying to create a own view. Now I found the usefull tutorial on [developer.android.net](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#subclassview). I followed the instroduction, but I have some trouble to use the view.

First, my folder structur

[image]

`cView.java`

```
package company.firstactivity.customViews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class cView extends View{
    public cView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }
}
```

`cViewAttributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="cView">
        <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.firstactivity.MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is the namespace to use the view. What is the namespace? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by namespace? Where did that come from?

Comment: You mean you want to know how to include your view at xml level?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Press on the link and then the point: **Define Custom Attributes**. ->  _Instead of belonging to the http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android namespace, they belong to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]_.

Comment: @thetonrifles correct. I want to use the custom view in the xml (with the attribute `showText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace in the xml can be anything but it should always have the value `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`. Please refer to `my_custom_namespace` in the following example to understand how you use it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:my_custom_namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.firstactivity.MainActivity">

    <company.firstactivity.customViews.cView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        my_custom_namespace:showText="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can change the `my_custom_namespace` to `app` or whatever you'd like to have.

On the other hand, if you'd like to use the custom attributes in the java code of your custom view you can read this value this way:

```
public cView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView(context, attrs);
}

public cView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView(context, attrs);
}

private void initView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.cView);
        boolean shouldShowText = styledAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.cView_showText, false);
        styledAttrs.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it works or if you have other questions regarding this. If not, you can accept the answer so others can take it as a reference.

Comment: yeha, your solution worked well. I accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use a custom view in XML, you have to use the fully specified name. This is the combination of the package with the class name. So yours would be `company.firstactivity.customViews.cView`

Answer (score 1):

you can move content of cViewAttributes.xml to file attire.xml in res/values

then in your layout xml you can declare xmlns

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and then you can use

```
app:showText="false"
```